# Change the message encoding of MsmqIntegrationBinding

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, msmq, msmqintegrationbinding

I'm trying to post a message on a MSMQ using WCF with a MsmqIntegrationbinding. Sending works but when I look at the message that has been sent to the queue. The encoding is incorrect.

Is it possible to change the message encoding to UTF-16? I already tried to solve this using a custom binding. This didn't solve my issue. I pasted the custom binding that I used below.

```
<binding name="CustomMsmqIntegrationBinding">   
   <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="None" writeEncoding="utf-16" />
   <msmqIntegration exactlyOnce="true">
      <msmqTransportSecurity msmqAuthenticationMode="None" msmqProtectionLevel="None" />
   </msmqIntegration>
</binding>
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is, do you have a reason that forces you to exactly use UTF-16?

Have you seen this link in the MSDN forums: ["How to make UTF-16 as default encoding for WCF Data Services."](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/ee5b91a0-0cb1-469f-b6dd-ef222e3f4e93)?

As a possible solution it suggests:

> The client can send Accept-Charset: utf-16 header in the request and
>   the server will respond using UTF-16.

And the accepted post says:

> [...] UTF-8 supports the exact same set of characters as
>   UTF-16. So unless you have a client which can only consume UTF-16 and
>   not UTF-8 there should be no reason to use UTF-16 over UTF-8. To the
>   contrary in fact, UTF-16 payloads are almost 2 times larger than
>   UTF-8.

Comment: The problem I have is that the application that is consuming the Queue won't pick up the messages. I thought this was because of the encoding of the message. The problem can lay somewhere else though.

The message that is being sent by the msmqIntegrationBinding is a binary xml file. The consuming application probably only accepts plain text. Do you know if it's possible to send the message as plain text to the Queue?

Comment: @Casper: The binary binding is default, so you want to try a custom binding like this:
`<customBinding name="msmqText">
    <msmqTransport ... />
    <textMessageEncoding ... />
</customBinding>`

But I am no expert in this. :(